# Compression in a sphere due to a sectoral load?

Tags: forces

I wish to know the net compression in a solid and hollow sphere when a radially perpendicular load is applied on a sector of its circumphery. Ex: on 2(pi)r/8 of the circumference. thanks

Comment: Can you use Hertzian contact stress theory for this? It will work for the solid sphere. You might be able to deduce the hollow sphere result by differentiating the result with respect to the radius.

Comment: Since the loading is not uniform (only convers part of the surface) you need to solve the Bussinesq energy integrals your self and there is no guarantee that there is a numetically stable solution either. At this point I recommend going the FEA way.

Comment: Note the theoretical deformation of a line load (force on circumferance) is infinite. You have to consider a certain pressure width to be able to apply Hertzian or non-Hertzian contact properties.